# Conditional Keybinding for gdb: gud-step if debugging, otherwise gud-run

Tags: gud, gdb

I have been trying around getting one keybinding `<F7>` to perform one `gud-step` command if a debugging process is running. If it is not running it shall perform `gud-run`.
I am not very familiar with gdb/gud yet, so while trying to get `gdb-running` to work as a condition for my defun I am exposed to lisp argument errors, that 2 arguments are required (string-or-char-p and nil), where the first argument is a token, as it seems.
In the end my goal is to use `<F7>` to invoke a `gud-run` and to step-through with the same key afterwards, after reaching a breakpoint.

Following snippet is my first attempt. It becomes obvious that `gdb-running` is missing 2 arguments as aforementioned.

```el
(require 'gud)
(defun my-gud-run-or-step ()
  (interactive)
  (if (gdb-running)
      (gud-step nil)
    (gud-run nil)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'my-gud-run-or-step)
```

Comment: Could you share the code you've written? It will make answering the question easier.

Comment: Where did you find out about `gdb-running`? I find only the **variable** `gud-running`.

Comment: I'd like to comment on my Question to answer JeanPierres Question, but apparently I have to reach a reputation of 50 first. I can find `gdb-running` for example by tab-completing in `M-:` Eval: while `gdb` is running.
`(defun gdb-running (_token output-field)` appears to be located in `gdb-mi.el.gz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error tells you that `gdb-running` needs two arguments, but that's kindof a red herring. `gdb-running` doesn't actually do what you want; it doesn't return true or false to tell you whether gdb is currently running. I think it's called when gdb starts receiving gdb's output, as it appears to set several state variables that are used elsewhere. It looks like you could use the `gud-running` variable, or `gdb-inferior-status`. The former will be `t`, and the latter will be `"running"`, so these might work:

```
(if gud-running
  ...)
```

or

```
(if (equal gdb-inferior-status "running")
  ...)
```

Comment: Very helpful. Since hitting a breakpoint `gud-running` doesn't seem to result in `t`. Instead; I now use `gdb-inferior-status` comparing to `"running"`,  `"end-stepping-range"` and `"breakpoint-hit"` to invoke `gud-step`.